# Parse UI elements

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am trying to find all the UI controls and controltypes in a large UI application built using Winforms and WPF (hybrid) programmatically. Is there a way I can use reflection to obtain all these information from the exe file?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to find the types for the controls that are in use? Or all that are defined within code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have .NET Reflector, you could try using that. Barring that, open the assembly in ildasm and browse through it manually.

Comment: I believe this is still not a programmatic approach to solve the problem. I want to write a program to perform the work automatically.